# How to easily determine input argument class (Project reactor context)

Tags: lambda, project-reactor

I am currently ramping up on the Project Reactor topic and I am playing around with *reactor.core.publisher.Mono* and *reactor.test.StepVerifier*.

Considering the following code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

public class ReactorTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Joe joe = new Joe();
    Mono<Bob> result = joe.doStuff();

    StepVerifier.create(result)
                .expectError(RuntimeException.class)
                .verifyThenAssertThat()
                .hasOperatorErrorsMatching(errorList -> true); //true to be replaced by validations 
  }

}
```

And

```
public interface Bob {

}
```

And

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class Joe {

  public Mono<Bob> doStuff() {

    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());

  }

}
```

I am trying to perform a bunch of validation inside the lambda expression of *.hasOperatorErrorsMatching(...)*

The *.hasOperatorErrorsMatching(...)* is defined as
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zydKX.png)

I find it really hard to determine the class type of *errorList* by looking at the .hasOperatorErrorsMatching(...) [doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/snapshot/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Assertions.html#hasOperatorErrorsMatching-java.util.function.Predicate-) and the input argument expression:

```
Predicate<Collection<Tuple2<Optional<Throwable>, Optional<?>>>> arg0
```

Am I the only one finding this expression hard to read?

Using the Eclipse debugger, I managed to determine the class type of [*errorList*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RniPZ.png) which you can see is *ConcurrentLinkedQueue*, with that I now have what I need to perform my validations in *.hasOperatorErrorsMatching(...)*.

**Question**: How do you determine the class type of *errorList* when writing your code? Do you check the debugger as I did or you have easier ways to determine it?

Comment: are you sure `hasOperatorErrorsMatching` is what you are after? The assertions after the verify block are here to assert internal state/Reactive Streams protocol errors, NOT the `error` signal from `expectError` a few lines above

Comment: Thx for your answer, I still want to know how if there is an easy to determine that errorList  will be an instance of ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>. 
Nevertheless,  I am interested to know how you would for example validate the error msg of the error signal from the expectError.